# Removing "White Character"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm sorry if type of this question has been ever asked before. However, I don't find any correct answer due to the question so far. I'm trying to remove any "white character" in my rows but not work.

I have a table with lots of "white character". I said "white character" cos I'm not sure it is the space character. I proved it by:

```
SELECT ASCII(RIGHT(myfield,1)) as expre1 FROM mytable
```

It gives me various of ASCII character that displayed as SPACE. I'm sure typing script something like this doesn't work.

```
SELECT replace(myfield, ' ', '') as expr1 FROM mytable
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(myfield)) as expr1 FROM mytable
```

Any idea how to remove such "white character" ?
Thank you.

Comment: What data type is myfield?

Comment: the data type is varchar(50)

Comment: You are looking for whitespace characters, which include at least the space, tab, carriage-return, line-feed, form-feed characters. I think Unicode (nvarchar) fields has even more whitespace characters like the non-breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

This works, [Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/654e3/17)

```
      SELECT
            [C] AS [data()]
        FROM (
            SELECT
                  substring([Test].[Data], v.Number+1, 1) [C]
              FROM (
                  SELECT [Data] FROM [Test]) [Test]
                    JOIN
                        master..spt_values [v]
                          ON [v].Number < LEN([Test].[Data])
                    WHERE
                        [v].type = 'P') [Test]
              WHERE
                  len(ltrim([Test].[C])) > 0
        FOR XML PATH('')
```

But TSQL is a really bad tool for the job.